# SSIS Azure Tools are greyed out in VS2019 Azure SSIS Toolbox

Tags: ssis

I am in the Government Azure Cloud. I am trying to run SSIS on my laptop locally but the Azure Tools in the SSIS Toolbox is always grayed out. See attachment. Any suggestions? I can not get an Azure Blob Component because of this.
THanks
MIke[image]

Comment: I think you just need to install the optional Azure componentry, yeah?

Comment: Thanks, but I did....its really strange...I wonder if it has something to do with the Government Azure Cloud? Thanks for your reply